# Dynamically setting a function in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using react+redux for an app and am trying to return an action based on index for the page currently being viewed.  The buttons are common across all pages, but the cancel and save action will need to do different things depending on the page.  Here's what I'm currently trying (without success):

```
const cancelAction = (slideIndex, actions) => {
  switch(slideIndex){
    case 0: return actions.cancelSlide0()
    case 1: return actions.cancelSlide1()
    case 2: return actions.cancelSlide2()
  }
}

const saveAction = (slideIndex, actions) => {
  switch(slideIndex){
    case 0: return actions.saveSlide0()
    case 1: return actions.saveSlide1()
    case 2: return actions.saveSlide2()
  }
}

const buttons = (actions, slideIndex) => (
  <div>
    <RaisedButton
      onTouchTap={() => cancelAction(actions, slideIndex)}  
      label={'CANCEL'}
      >
    </RaisedButton>
    <RaisedButton
      onTouchTap={() => saveAction(actions, slideIndex)}
     label={'SAVE'}
    >
    </RaisedButton>
  </div>
)
```

How can I properly implement this type of logic?

Comment: is it not working? It looks okay...

Comment: F12, any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you have your parameters mixed up? 
    `const cancelAction = (slideIndex, actions) => {`

But you're calling it as 
    `cancelAction(actions, slideIndex)`

Answer (score 0):

Shoot - you guys were spot on.  For some silly reason I wasn't paying attention to the console.  There was a typo in one of the constant names, once I changed that and everything started working as expected.  Thank you!